# Number of iterations needed for a vector repeatedly multiplied by a matrix to converge.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

This is my first post on here, sorry for any formatting issues. This process I believe is called a Markov chain, but I don't have the necessary math knowledge required to understand it fully. Essentially, I have a vector in the form:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & ...  & 0
\end{pmatrix}
I also have a matrix where the sum of each row is 1 (Edit: all elements must be positive as well). An example is the following matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
1/6 & 2/3 & 1/6\\
5/12 & 1/6 & 5/12\\
1/6 & 2/3 & 1/6
\end{pmatrix}

The vector is repeatedly multiplied by the matrix, until the Euclidean difference of the vector between iterations is below a certain threshold value.

My question is, is there a way to find the expected number of iterations required? For example, for a threshold value of 0.0001, I found empirically that the number of iterations was about 30, and also that the size of the matrix/vector does not affect this value. Is there a way to confirm this?

Comment: If you used this 3 by 3 matrix, it must have been start vector with 3 components, as in say (1,0,0). Is that what you did? (because when you described the vector it looked like it had an unspecified number of components)

Comment: Yes, the vector would be (1, 0, 0) in this case. I just wrote it that way because the sizes of the vector and matrix could be anything, and I'm trying to find a general solution.

Comment: So you say the matrix size did not affect required iterations until threshhold achieved. Do you also mean the individual matrix entries did not affect number of iterations? [That would seem surprising (to me) as some matrices are more "ill conditioned" than others and one would think would take longer to converge]

Comment: Take $$P=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ and $x=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, then clearly $xP^n$ does not converge as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Math1000 that's a good counter example., and I hadn't consider that. However, I think in this case such matrices would not show up, as in the problem I'm working with, all entries are non-zero. Would the property that P^n always converge as n goes to infinity hold true given this?

Comment: Indeed, the existence of a positive integer $n$ such that all entries of $P^n$ are positive is equivalent to the existence of a limit $P_\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty}P^n$ whose rows are identically $\pi$ and satisfy $\pi P=\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sum of each row is $1$, then the $m \times m$ matrix $P$ is a right stochastic matrix.

Assuming you can diagonalize $P$, then

$ P = V D V^{-1} $

Now,

$ x_{n+1} = P x_{n} = V D V^{-1} x_n $

Hence,

$ x_n = V D^{n} V^{-1} x_0 $

The elements of $D$ can be ordered in descending order from $1$ down to the smallest eigenvalue in absolute value.  That is,

$ 1 = \lambda_1 \gt | \lambda_2 | \ge | \lambda_3 | \ge \dots \ge | \lambda_m | $

From the last equation, we can write,

$ V^{-1} x_n = D^n V^{-1} x_0 $

Define $y_n = V^{-1} x_n$

Then

$ y_n = D^n y_0 $

As $n \to \infty$, $y_n \to y_\infty = [ y_{01} , 0, 0, \dots , 0]^T $

Now,

$ y_n - y_\infty = D^n y_0 - e_1 e_1^T y_0 = [ D^n - e_1 e_1^T ] y_0 $

The matrix $[ D^n - e_1 e_1^T] $ has a zero $(1,1)$ entry, and the rest of the diagonal elemens are $\lambda_2^n, \lambda_3^n , \dots , \lambda_m^n$. Since $\lambda_2 $ is greater in absolute value than all the other eigenvalues, it is dominant.  Therefore, for $n$ sufficiently large, we have

$ \| y_n - y_\infty \| = \| V^{-1} (x_n - x_\infty ) \| \approx |\lambda_2|^n \| y_0 \| = |\lambda_2|^n \| V^{-1} x_0 \| $

But,

$ \| V^{-1} (x_n - x_\infty ) \| \le L_{max} \| x_n - x_\infty \| $

and

$ \| V^{-1} x_0 \| \ge L_{min} \| x_0 \| $

where $L_{max}$ and $L_{min} $ are the maximum and minimum square roots of the eigenvalues of $V^{-T} V^{-1} $ (i.e. the maximum and minimum singular values of $V^{-1}$).

Therefore,

$ L_{min} \| x_0 \| | \lambda_2 |^n  \le L_{max} \| x_n  -  x_\inf \| $

Now, we want $ \| x_n - x_\infty \| \le \varepsilon $, then will have

$ L_{min} \|x_0 \| |\lambda_2|^n \le L_{max}  \varepsilon $

Which implies

$ n \ge \dfrac{ \log( L_{max} \varepsilon) - \log( L_{min} \| x_0 \| ) }{ \log | \lambda_2 | } $

I've implemented the repeated multiplication, and cross checked the number of iterations required with that given by the above formula, and the two match.  For the given $3 \times 3$ example, and with $\varepsilon = 10^{-8}$, and the initial vector being $e_1$, the number of iterations required is $27$ as obtained by direct evaluation, and by the above formula.

As another example, consider the $4 \times 4$ matrix

$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 0.1 && 0.3 && 0.2 && 0.4 \\
0.5 && 0.1 && 0.2 && 0.2 \\
0.15 && 0.3 && 0.05&& 0.5 \\
0.7 && 0.2 && 0.05 && 0.05 \end{bmatrix} $

And let $\varepsilon = 10^{-8} $ and $x_0 = [1, 2, 3, 4]^T $

The actual minimum number of multiplications necessary to get $\| x_n - x_\infty \| \lt \varepsilon $ was $ 23 $.  While the value obtained with the formula is $21$.  The reason for the discrepancy is that we made an approximation about the magnitude of $\| x_n - x_\infty \|$ and based it solely on $|\lambda_2|^n$ (when in fact, it is a function of the other eigenvalues as well).

As a third example, let the $5 \times 5$ matrix $P$ be given by

$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 0.15 && 0.25 && 0.25 && 0.25 && 0.1 \\ 0.1 && 0.3 && 0.2 && 0.2 && 0.2 \\ 0.15 && 0.25 && 0.15 && 0.4 && 0.05 \\ 0.1 && 0.2 && 0.3 && 0.4 && 0 \\ 0.15 && 0.15 && 0.15 && 0.15 && 0.4 \end{bmatrix} $

And let $ \varepsilon = 10^{-8} $ and $ x_0 =[1,2,3,4,5]^T $

The actual number of iterations required was $19$.  In contrast, the number of iterations predicted by the formula is $20$.